# directory name with space and bash

Tags: bash, command-line, scripts, rsync

I'd like to exclude the directories "temp" and "Ubuntu One/" from backup. What is the correct escaping of the space????

```
RSYNCCONF="--delete --exclude=.* --exclude=temp/"
```

Thanks in advance!

- Chris

Edit/PS:

```
excludes=( ".*" temp/ "Ubuntu One/" )' 'RSYNCCONF="${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}"
```

and

```
$RSYNC -e "$S" -avR $FROMSSH:$SOURCE ${RSYNCCONF[@]} $TARGET$TODAY $INC >> $LOG 2>&1
```

didn't work. I'd really appreciate any advice.

This is the script: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/_attachment?target=Skripte%2FBackup_mit_RSYNC%2Fbackup.sh

Answer (score 7):

If you're building up options in a string, you'll run into problems when you try to use it (`rsync "$RSYNCCONF"`). 
Better to use an array -- when you dereference the array, each element will be properly handled by the shell:

```
RSYNCCONF=( --delete '--exclude=.*' --exclude=temp/ '--exclude="Ubuntu One/"' )
rsync "${RSYNCCONF[@]}"
```

Comment: Well, I copied the whole script from http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/_attachment?target=Skripte%2FBackup_mit_RSYNC%2Fbackup.sh I don't know how to handle all the other options so I'll try Rajish's reply next time. Won't it work?

Comment: You need to lose the outer quotes on the last --exclude there.

Comment: @chris I'm afraid that script is quite badly written, so it's not a good script to use as a template.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. When I use an array like in glenn's or geirha's reply, what do I write in line 53 for example? `$RSYNC -e "$S" -avR $FROMSSH:$SOURCE "${RSYNCCONF[@]}"
 $TARGET$TODAY $INC >> $LOG 2>&1` Simply replace `$RSYNCCONF` with the array?

Comment: 'excludes=( ".*" temp/ "Ubuntu One/" )'
'RSYNCCONF="${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}"' and '$RSYNC -e "$S" -avR $FROMSSH:$SOURCE ${RSYNCCONF[@]} $TARGET$TODAY $INC >> $LOG 2>&1 ' didn't work. I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: @chris well yes, the whole point of using an array instead of a string was to be able to handle things like whitespace in filenames. You mangled the array back into a string, and thus broke it. `rsync ... --delete "${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}" ...`. Seriously though, I was too kind in my last comment. The script is unreadable garbage. The author clearly doesn't know bash. If you instead explain what you actually need the script to do, the solution will probably be less than five lines.

Comment: @geihra, I changed the script like this http://pastebin.com/pmvpHBBU but it doesn't work. The script should only create a backup of my files each day in a directory named 2011-06-15 and so on. If files didn't change, symlinks should be set. That's rsync's job. That's all. All the other stuff in this script isn't needed. I guess they also backup a debian-package list or something like that...

Comment: @chris, see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into single quotes:

```
RSYNCCONF="--delete --exclude=.* --exclude=temp/ --exclude='Ubuntu One/' "
```

or put a backslash before the space:

```
RSYNCCONF="--delete --exclude=.* --exclude=temp/ --exclude=Ubuntu\\ One/ "
```

Comment: You can't put syntactical quotes inside quotes. An array is the only sane way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
excludes=( ".*" temp/ "Ubuntu One/" )
rsync --delete "${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}"
```

Note that the above uses bash syntax, so it won't work with sh. Also, the quotes are vital, do not omit them.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting for an explanation of why putting more than one argument into a string variable is wrong.

EDIT: From the pastebin in your comments, this seems to be what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/home/chris/
backupdir=/media/alteplatte/backups
backupname=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-cd
excludes=( ".*" temp/ "Ubuntu One/" )
linkdest=$backupdir/link

if [[ -d $backupdir ]]; then
    rsync -av ${linkdest:+"--link-dest=$linkdest"} --delete \
          "${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}" "$source" "$backupdir/$backupname"
else
    echo "$0: $backupdir: Not a directory, make sure the filesystem is mounted" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Dear geirha, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know anything about bash-scripting. Now I've a reliable backup! Thanks again.